# How to set a hidden field value based on a value inside an image with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a several images like this:

```
<div class="attribImg"><img data-id="9" src="images/attributes/black.jpg" alt="Black"></div>
<div class="attribImg"><img data-id="3" src="images/attributes/red.jpg" alt="Black"></div>
<div class="attribImg"><img data-id="7" src="images/attributes/green.jpg" alt="Black"></div>
<div class="attribImg"><img data-id="8" src="images/attributes/blue.jpg" alt="Black"></div>
```

... and a hidden data field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id[1]" name="id[1]" value="1">
```

I am looking for the correct way to change the value of the hidden input on click of the images based on what is set with `data-id` in the images.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, this can be achieved like this:

```
   $('.attribImg').on('click', function () {
    var value = $(this).children('img').data('id');
    alert(value)
    $('#id').val(value);
});
```

**UPDATE**:
The reason the value will not be set is because you have used `[]` in the id name which is reserved. You are only permitted to use letters(Aa-Zz),digits(0-9),hyphens(-), underscores(_) or colons(:) in that order. There is a good explaination [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bgce399j/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, the Alert works, but it doesn't set the value of the hidden field.

Comment: @user2924019 you need to use a different id name instead of `id[1]`. check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to the below maybe:

```
$("input:image").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $("#id[1]").val($(this).attr('data-id'));
    });
});
```